# JSON error upon initial Office 1.1 API Load

Tags: office-js

I get the following error message in the browser console after performing `yo office`, starting browser sync (Yes I self signed), and opening index.html.

[image]

Office.initialize is never invoked, and there are no instances of Powerpoint, Word, Excel, etc that I can reference to start digging around in the API. My guess is this exception is blocking further execution of whatever it is the Office API does.

Attempts to try to get this to work by uploading the addin are also met with the exact same error. I can't find documentation on this issue anywhere and no one seems to know what this means. I've tried digging around both the code and related projects but I don't have the slightest clue what's going on.

Anyone has any insight or leads?

Edit: Included Screenshot
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This error is triggered when you attempt to load an add-in by directly opening the URI in a browser. Add-ins are intended to be run from within an Office application's context, they are not standalone web apps.

In order to launch your add-in, you must first [side-load your manifest](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/testing/create-a-network-shared-folder-catalog-for-task-pane-and-content-add-ins) into the appropriate Office host.

I would suggest starting with the [Office Add-in Overview](https://dev.office.com/docs/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins).

Comment: This error is occuring from within the context of an Office application. I know the screenshot shows otherwise but it happens in both locations.

That being said, the Office 13 API's are working completely fine. After doing some more digging, I can narrow down my problem more specifically to the fact that the Office 16 API's don't seem to be working at all but that is a seperate question now I realize.

Comment: Ah, thank you for clarifying. Could you provide a larger screenshot with the add-in running? It would also help to understand which platform and build number your testing on as well as which method you used to side-loading the add-in.

Comment: I edited my original question. Once the edit is approved it should appear. I side-loaded this via the "Upload Add-ins" option.

Comment: Looks like you attempted to edit my answer, not your original question.

Comment: That would explain why I've never seen that screen before! Edited my question.